# str_extract all syntax

Tags: r, string, extract, stringr

I need some help with `stringr::str_extract_all`

`x` is the name of my data frame.

```
V1
(A_K9B,A_K9one,A_K9two,B_U10J)
```

```
x = x %>% 
  mutate(N_alph = map_chr(str_extract_all(x$V1, 'A_([A-Z][0-10])[A-Z]'), toString))
x = x %>% 
  mutate(N_.1 = map_chr(str_extract_all(x$V1, 'A_([A-Z][0-10])[o][n][e]'), toString))
x = x %>% 
  mutate(N_.2 = map_chr(str_extract_all(x$V1, 'A_([A-Z][0-10])[t][w][o]'), toString))
```

This is my current output:

```
V1                                N_alph  N_.1     N_.2
(A_K9B,A_K9one,A_K9two,B_U10J)   A_K9B   A_K9one  A_K9two
```

I am fine with my column `N_alph` as is I want it separate from the other two. But Ideally I would like to avoid typing `[o][n][e]` and `[t][w][o]` for those variables that are followed by words rather than one alphabetical letter, if I use:

```
x = x %>% 
  mutate(N_alph = map_chr(str_extract_all(x$V1, 'A_([A-Z][0-10])[A-Z]'), toString))
x = x %>% 
  mutate(N_all.words = map_chr(str_extract_all(x$V1, 'A_([A-Z][0-10])[\\w+]'), toString))
```

Output is:

```
V1                                N_alph  N_all.words    
(A_K9B,A_K9one,A_K9two,B_U10J)   A_K9B   A_K9B,A_K9o,A_K9t
```

Desired output would be

```
V1                                N_alph  N_all.words    
(A_K9B,A_K9one,A_K9two,B_U10J)   A_K9B   A_K9one,A_K9two
```

Comment: Input, Output, and desired output are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use metacharacters like \w, \b, \s, etc., you don't need the square brackets. But if you do use the square brackets than the `+` would need to be outside. Also, the number group should be [0-9] as we are talking about individual characters, not combinations of characters. To take into account numbers higher than 9 we just expand the amount of times we check for the group with {} brackets, or simply the `+` operator. The final result looks like so:

```
x %>% 
  mutate(N_all.words = str_extract_all(V1, 'A_([A-Z][0-9]{1,2})\\w+'))
```

Resulting to:

```
                              V1             N_all.words
1 (A_K9B,A_K9one,A_K9two,B_U10J) A_K9B, A_K9one, A_K9two
```

I also created a version that I found a little tidier:

```
x %>% 
  mutate(N_all.words = str_extract_all(V1, 'A_\\w\\d{1,2}\\w+'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am just unsure if I understand {1,2}, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: {1,2} means that the amount of digits you expect is either 1 or 2. If you have for example "A_Z111three" it won't extract, because it there are 3 consecutive digits. If you want to be more lenient and allow any number of digits you can change to \\d+ or [0-9]+